# I will not let anyone enter my backend URL - Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

[This problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuMAf.png)
I want to know how to secure my back and request a URL.
At first, I didn’t put any authcation on my project.

Now what I want to do is aunt - if anyone visits my URL, I will not let them see that page.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py add below code

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

So the setting will become global

You can learn about permissions from this link https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/